# Recorrer TextBox de DataGridView

Tags: vb.net

Que tal, tengo una aplicación Windows Forms en la cual en un `TextBox` simulo el nombre de una tabla, en otro ingreso las filas que tendra la tabla y en los 4 restantes las 4 columnas que contendra la tabla.

Dicho archivo me genera un archivo CSV y un archivo txt con la sintáxis SQL para crear la consulta. El problema es que yo quiero agregar los número de campos que sean, puede ser 1, 10, 100, etcétera. Agregarlos en TextBox sería un poco complicado y la verdad no encuentro la manera de como hacerlo.

A continuación dejo imágenes de los archivos generados y el código fuente que es lo que realiza actualmente. Espero puedan ayudarme.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que utilizo es el siguiente:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO

Public Partial Class MainForm

    Public Sub New()
        ' The Me.InitializeComponent call is required for Windows Forms designer support.
        Me.InitializeComponent()
    '
    ' TODO : Add constructor code after InitializeComponents
    '
    End Sub

    Dim nombres As String() = {"Aaron", "Abel", "Abelardo", "Abraham", "Adalberto", "Adolfo", "Adrian", "Agustin", "Alan", "Alejandro", "Benjamin", "Bernardo", "Baldomero", "Baltasar", "Barack", "Josh"}

    Dim apellidos As String() = {"Pineda", "Bernal", "Espinoza", "Spindola", "Brisuela", "Gutierrez", "Escarcega", "Muñiz", "Lopez", "Martinez", "Piña", "Vega", "Ortiz", "Barcenas", "Lopez", "Martinez"}

    Dim paises As String() = {"Estados Unidos", "Mexico", "Costa Rica", "Jamaica", "Panama", "Haiti", "Colombia", "Venezuela", "Ecuador", "Peru", "Bolivia", "Chile", "Brasil", "Uruguay", "Paraguay", "Argentina"}

    Sub BtnCrearClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Const separador = ";"
        Const folder = "C:\Users\desarrollo\Documents\CSV"
        Const titulo = "archivo.csv"
        Dim headers As String() = {txtID.Text, txtNombre.Text, txtApp.Text, txtApm.Text}
        Dim filePath = Path.Combine(folder, titulo)
        Dim sw As New StreamWriter(filePath, False, Encoding.UTF8)
        sw.WriteLine(String.Join(separador, headers))
        Dim aleatorio As New Random
        For i = 1 To Convert.ToInt32(txtFilas.Text)
            Dim fields As String() = {i.ToString(), nombres(aleatorio.Next(0, nombres.Length)), apellidos(aleatorio.Next(0, apellidos.Length)), paises(aleatorio.Next(0, paises.Length))}
            sw.WriteLine(String.Join(separador, fields))
        Next

        sw.Close
    'Dim row As DataRow 
    'Dim i As Integer
    'For i=1 To Convert.ToInt32(txtFilas.Text)
    'row=TablaNombres.NewRow()
    'row(txtID.Text)=i
    'If cbo2.SelectedItem = "Nombres" Then
    'row(txtNombre.Text)=nombres(aleatorio.Next(0,nombres.Length))
    'ElseIf cbo2.SelectedItem = "Apellidos"
    'row(txtNombre.Text)=apellidos(aleatorio.Next(0,apellidos.Length))
    'ElseIf cbo2.SelectedItem = "Paises"
    'row(txtNombre.Text)=paises(aleatorio.Next(0,paises.Length))
    'End If
    'If cbo3.SelectedItem="Nombres" Then
    'row(txtApp.Text)=nombres(aleatorio.Next(0,nombres.Length)) 
    'ElseIf cbo3.SelectedItem="Apellidos"
    'row(txtApp.Text)=apellidos(aleatorio.Next(0,nombres.Length))   
    'ElseIf cbo3.SelectedItem="Paises"
    'row(txtApp.Text)=paises(aleatorio.Next(0, paises.Length))
    'End If
    'If cbo4.SelectedItem="Nombres" Then
    'row(txtApm.Text)=nombres(aleatorio.Next(0,nombres.Length))
    'ElseIf cbo4.SelectedItem="Apellidos"
    'row(txtApm.Text)=apellidos(aleatorio.Next(0,nombres.Length))
    'ElseIf cbo4.SelectedItem="Paises"
    'row(txtApm.Text)=paises(aleatorio.Next(0,nombres.Length))
    'End If
    'TablaNombres.Rows.Add(row)
    'Next
    'tabla1.DataSource=TablaNombres
    'For i=1 To Convert.ToInt32(txtFilas.Text)
    'MsgBox("INSERT INTO " & txtTabla.Text & " (" & txtID.Text & ", " & txtNombre.Text & ", " & txtApp.Text & ", " & txtApm.Text & ") VALUES (" & i & ",'" & nombres(aleatorio.Next(0,nombres.Length)) &"','" & apellidos(aleatorio.Next(0,apellidos.Length)) &"','" & paises(aleatorio.Next(0,paises.Length)) &"')", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
    'Next
    End Sub

    Sub BtnSQLClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Const separador = ";"
        Const folder = "C:\Users\desarrollo\Documents\CSV"
        Const titulo = "archivo.txt"
        'Dim headers As String()={txtID.Text, txtNombre.Text, txtApp.Text, txtApm.Text}
        Dim filePath = Path.Combine(folder, titulo)
        Dim sw As New StreamWriter(filePath, False, Encoding.UTF8)
        'sw.WriteLine(String.Join(separador, headers))
        Dim aleatorio As New Random
        For i = 1 To Convert.ToInt32(txtFilas.Text)
            Dim insert As String = "INSERT INTO " & txtTabla.Text & " (" & txtID.Text & ", " & txtNombre.Text & ", " & txtApp.Text & ", " & txtApm.Text & ") VALUES (" & i & ",'" & nombres(aleatorio.Next(0, nombres.Length)) & "','" & apellidos(aleatorio.Next(0, apellidos.Length)) & "','" & paises(aleatorio.Next(0, paises.Length)) & "')"
            sw.WriteLine(String.Join(separador, insert))
        Next

        sw.Close
    End Sub

    Sub MainFormLoad(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar un control [DataGridView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx) (DGV) para el ingreso de los nombres de campos y tipos de datos:

```
Me.DataGridView1.Columns.Add("NombreCampo", "Nombre del campo")
Me.DataGridView1.Columns.Add("TipoDatos", "Tipo de datos")
```

Luego se puede crear el esquema de la tabla, a continuación randomizar y finalmente grabar las instrucciones insert:

```
Sub BtnSQLClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ' Crea una DataTable según el esquema dado por el usuario a través del DataGridView.'
    Dim dt As DataTable = CreaTabla(Me.DataGridView1, txtTabla.Text)

    ' Crea una DataTable Random para los nombres, apellidos y países.'
    Dim dtRandom As DataTable = CreaDataTableRandom()

    ' Asigna los valores aleatorios a dt.'
    LLenaAlAzar(dtRandom, dt, Me.txtFilas.Text)

    ' Graba las instrucciones Insert.'
    GrabaInserts(dt)
End Sub
```

El usuario especifica las características de la tabla en el DGV. Entonces con **CreaTabla** se convierte esa tabla en una [DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Private Function CreaTabla(dgvTabla As DataGridView, NombreTabla As String) As DataTable
    Dim tabla As DataTable = New DataTable(NombreTabla)

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvTabla.Rows
        ' No tenemos en cuenta la fila NewRow.'
        If row.IsNewRow Then
            Continue For
        End If

        ' Extraemos los nombres de los campos.'
        Dim column As DataColumn = tabla.Columns.Add(row.Cells("NombreCampo").Value.ToString)

        Select Case row.Cells("TipoDatos").Value.ToString.ToUpper
            Case "ENTERO"
                column.DataType = GetType(Integer)

            Case "TEXTO"
                column.DataType = GetType(String)
        End Select
    Next

    Return tabla
End Function
```

Para randomizar existen varias opciones, una de las cuales puede ser:

```
Private Function CreaDataTableRandom() As DataTable
    Dim nombres As String() = {"Aaron", "Abel", "Abelardo", "Abraham", "Adalberto", "Adolfo", "Adrian", "Agustin", "Alan", "Alejandro", "Benjamin", "Bernardo", "Baldomero", "Baltasar", "Barack", "Josh"}
    Dim apellidos As String() = {"Pineda", "Bernal", "Espinoza", "Spindola", "Brisuela", "Gutierrez", "Escarcega", "Muñiz", "Lopez", "Martinez", "Piña", "Vega", "Ortiz", "Barcenas", "Lopez", "Martinez"}
    Dim paises As String() = {"Estados Unidos", "Mexico", "Costa Rica", "Jamaica", "Panama", "Haiti", "Colombia", "Venezuela", "Ecuador", "Peru", "Bolivia", "Chile", "Brasil", "Uruguay", "Paraguay", "Argentina"}

    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable("Random")

    dt.Columns.Add("nombre", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("apellido", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("pais", GetType(String))

    ' Se tiene en cuenta el superíndice más alto.'
    For i As Integer = 0 To Math.Max(nombres.Length, Math.Max(apellidos.Length, paises.Length)) - 1
        ' El operador Mod es necesario en caso que los vectores sean de diferente tamaño.'
        dt.Rows.Add(nombres(i Mod nombres.Length), apellidos(i Mod apellidos.Length), paises(i Mod paises.Length))
    Next

    Return dt
End Function


Private Sub LLenaAlAzar(dtOrigen As DataTable, dtDestino As DataTable, numFilas As Integer)
    Dim aleatorio As New Random

    For i As Integer = 1 To numFilas

        Dim dr As DataRow = dtDestino.NewRow

        ' Asignamos los valores aleatorios, desde dtOrigen hacia dtDestino.'
        For j As Integer = 0 To dtOrigen.Columns.Count - 1
            Dim filaRandom As Integer = aleatorio.Next(0, dtOrigen.Rows.Count)
            Dim nombreCampo As String = dtOrigen.Columns(j).ColumnName
            dr(nombreCampo) = dtOrigen.Rows(filaRandom)(j)
        Next

        dtDestino.Rows.Add(dr)
    Next
End Sub
```

Las instrucciones **Insert** se pueden guardar con:

```
Private Sub GrabaInserts(dt As DataTable)
    ' Molde para la sentencia Insert.'
    Dim moldeInsert As String = CreaMoldeInsert(dt)

    Dim valores As System.Text.StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder

    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows

        valores.Clear()

        For Each column As DataColumn In dt.Columns

            Dim valor As String = row(column).ToString

            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(valor.Trim) Then
                valores.Append("null")
            Else
                ' Encerramos el valor entre comillas, dependiendo del tipo de datos.'
                ' Usamos Select Case por si hubiesen varios tipos de datos que necesiten un formato especial.'
                Select Case column.DataType
                    Case GetType(Integer)   ' No necesita formato especial.'
                        valores.Append(valor)

                    Case GetType(String)    ' Necesita ir entre comillas simples.'
                        valores.Append("'")
                        valores.Append(valor)
                        valores.Append("'")
                End Select
            End If

            ' El último campo no lleva separador al final.'
            If column.Ordinal < dt.Columns.Count - 1 Then
                valores.Append(CONST_SEPARADOR)
            End If
        Next

        ' Insert completa.'
        Dim insert As String = moldeInsert.Replace("valores", valores.ToString)

        ' La salida es por consola, por motivos de depuración, pero se puede convertir fácilmente en flujo con el código de la pregunta.'
        debug.WriteLine(insert)
    Next
End Sub


Public Function CreaMoldeInsert(dt As DataTable) As String

    Dim campos As System.Text.StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder(dt.Columns(0).ColumnName)

    For i As Integer = 1 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
        campos.Append(",")
        campos.Append(dt.Columns(i).ColumnName)
    Next

    Return CONST_INSERT.Replace("tabla", dt.TableName).Replace("campos", campos.ToString)
End Function
```

Las constantes utilizadas son:

```
Const CONST_INSERT As String = "INSERT INTO tabla (campos) VALUES (valores)"
Const CONST_SEPARADOR As String = ","
```

Es lo más simple que pude hacer. Tal vez otro programador más avanzado pueda ayudar a simplificar el código.